# Error when testing application on iPod

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4

I am developing a iphone application. It is working fine on iPhone Simulator 4.0 but when I test it on my iPod (My iPod has latest version 4.0) then I get the error :

**Couldn't register com.myApp with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.**

& hang the application.

Please suggest me any idea how I resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting Xcode and/or your Mac/iOS device. This usually fixes errors like this for me.

Comment: Thanks for reply...I restarted Xcode..now it is giving this error....." 
-[UIWebDocumentView anchorPoint]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x832600
2010-07-07 17:19:58.786 RCS[109:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIWebDocumentView anchorPoint]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x832600'
*** Call stack at first throw:"
Even I am not using UIWebDocumentView anywhere in My application..

Comment: Seems like your trying to call a method on a released object (which points to something random - in this case UIWebDocumentView).

Comment: I suggest you set the status of the original question to 'answered', since it is, well, answered ;)

Could you fix your other problem?